# How to pass a variable to a function from a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am using a `SoftDeletableModel` model from [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#softdeletablemodel), which is an abstract base class model with a `is_removed` field that marks entries that are not going to be used anymore, but are kept in db for any reason.

It has the following structure:

```
class SoftDeletableModel(models.Model):

    is_removed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = SoftDeletableManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()

    def delete(self, using=None, soft=True, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Soft delete object (set its ``is_removed`` field to True).
        Actually delete object if setting ``soft`` to False.
        """
        if soft:
            self.is_removed = True
            self.save(using=using)
        else:
            return super().delete(using=using, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the event I actually want to delete an object rather than set `is_removed=True`, I need to add `soft=False` in the delete process.

How would I go about doing this in a view/template?

Comment: Have you tried instance.delete(soft=False)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `soft=False` as a keyword argument to the instance's delete method:

`your_object_instance.delete(soft=False)`

This can be done in your view function, or any other python file in your project where you are able to access this object instance.

Comment: How would I go about doing this in a view/template?

Comment: @alias51I would strongly advise against deleting any instances, soft or otherwise, in your templates. Logic like that is better placed in python code like view or utility functions. This is why Django template specifically don't allow you to run any python code you want within them.